# Cisco ASA Security Contexts: Any Real World Installs?

Tags: network, firewalls, cisco

We are looking at deploying a Cisco ASA 5520-I am looking at the security contexts feature, and was wondering if anyone has deployed their ASA in this way, and how it is working out for them.

Have you encountered anything that you wished you would have known before you deployed it?

Have you noticed any performance issues?

Is there anybody actually using this feature?

-Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context works great, what you want to know before deploying it is the unsupported feature in context mode: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/contexts.html#wp1146747

I never see any performance drop when enabling context mode

Answer (score 0):

The only gothcha I have seen I have seen in this deployment scenario is: " Cascading contexts requires that you configure unique MAC addresses for each context interface. Because of the limitations of classifying packets on shared interfaces without MAC addresses, we do not recommend using cascading contexts without unique MAC addresses."

Also the not supported - VPN and dynamic routing protocols.

I have seen 3 Contexts working on a ASA 5520 with no problems in a 30MB Inet connection.